# Can different api gateway stages have different numbers of resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to have a separate api gateway stage, which would have only a subset of endpoints from the "dev" stage.
So I would have "dev" stage - which would consist of 5 api endpoints.
And I want to create a new stage called "partial" which would consist of only 1 methods from those 5 from "dev".

I am failing to do so, when I create a new stage it has all those previous endpoints. I don't want that is this achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

It is sort of achievable. If you deploy "version 1" of your API to dev stage and then create a prod stage from that same deployment, you will have version 1 deployment on both stages. However, if you now deploy "version 2" of your API (which has more resources) to dev stage ONLY; then you would end up with "version 2" on dev stage but prod stage would still have the old deployment running.

After all, when you create a stage you choose which deployment you want to use for that stage so if you divide your API on two different deployments then you can choose one or the other depending on your needs.

There is a workaround that I do not recommend, to be honest, but it would work which is throttling that specific resource on prod stage resources settings.